# Validate input of a scanner: is it an integer and within a certain number range?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new at programming and I am currently following a Java class where I must validate a user's scanner input. The code below seems to work but I think it's a little bit inefficient. There must be a better way to do this!

Your suggestions are welcome!

Here's what I've got:

```
do {
    System.out.println("What is you age?");
    while (!scSudoku.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("You must enter an number");
        scSudoku.next();
    }
    age = scSudoku.nextInt();
    if (age < 10 || age > 90) {
        System.out.println("You age must be within 10 and 90");
    }
} while (age < 10 || age > 90);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextLine()` to discard any bad input.

Prevent code-duplication by using a never-ending loop, and either `break` or `return` to exit the loop. I prefer isolating the code in a helper method and use `return`.

```
private static int promptAge(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("What is you age?");
    for (;;) {
        if (! sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("You must enter an number");
        } else {
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            if (age >= 10 && age <= 90)
                return age;
            System.out.println("You age must be within 10 and 90");
        }
        sc.nextLine(); // discard (rest of) line of input
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `scSudoku.next();` with `scSudoku.nextLine`. It might run a little smoother, but my Java is a little rusty.
I remember using `nextLine` or `nextln` instead of just `next`, and the programs worked.

EDIT:
Try replacing `scSudoku.next();` with `scSudoku.nextln`. It appears that `nextln` is more widely used.

EDIT 2:
Or just use `nextWhateverYou'reUsing`.

Comment: Java's [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) does not have a `nextln()` method.

Comment: If that's the case, can you provide link to javadoc defining `nextln()` method? And perhaps reference to or example of the "more widely used" statement?

Comment: Probably, but not immediately; I'm at a different computer right now, and it doesn't have Java installed. When I get to my normal computer, I will get right on it (meaning searching through the java.util.Scanner class).

Comment: Sorry about that, you were right. But it always worked, I just don't know why.