# try-catch with do while

Tags: java, oop, try-catch, do-while

Hey I am new to java and I would like you to assist me guys.

I have trying to make try and catch work with do while but my attempts failed.

Basically what I want is this:

I am trying to build this library management system and I have a menu which consists of Guest, Administrator, Librarian and Exit.

So whenever I enter invalid number that's not in the range from 1 to 4 I want it to display my message that the number is invalid and whenever I enter an alphabet I want it to display an error saying I should enter an integer.

I have been trying to solve but I couldn't work it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
package excercises;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Excercises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ch;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
        try{
            System.out.println("1- GUEST");
            System.out.println("2- ADMINISTRATOR");
            System.out.println("3- LIBRARIAN");
            System.out.println("4- EXIT");
            System.out.println("* SELECT CHOICE: ");
            ch = input.nextInt();

            if (ch == 1)
                System.out.println("WELCOME GUEST \n");
            else if (ch == 2)
                     System.out.println("WELCOME ADMIN \n");
                 else if (ch == 3)
                          System.out.println("WELCOME LIBRARIAN \n");
                      else if (ch == 4)
                               System.out.println("THANK YOU , SEE YA SOON");
                           else
                               System.out.println("\t\n WRONG CHOICE PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBAAA \n");

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("input should be integer, EXITING ..");
            }    
    }while (ch !=4);


    }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate input of a scanner: is it an integer and within a certain number range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907581/validate-input-of-a-scanner-is-it-an-integer-and-within-a-certain-number-range)

Comment: Please be precise about the way your program's behaviour differs from what you want.

Comment: You should (1) almost never catch `Exception` itself, and (2) never "swallow" the error (what if the exception is `EOFException`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I changed your code look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String ch = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("1- GUEST");
            System.out.println("2- ADMINISTRATOR");
            System.out.println("3- LIBRARIAN");
            System.out.println("4- EXIT");



            boolean test = false;

            while (test == false) {
                 System.out.println("* SELECT CHOICE: ");
                String regex = "\\d+";
                ch = input.next();
                test = ch.matches(regex);
                if (test == false) {
                    System.out.println("There is a problem try again");
                }
                else if(Integer.valueOf(ch) > 4 ||  Integer.valueOf(ch) < 1){
                     System.out.println("Select a number from 1 to 4");
                     test =false;
                }
            }


            if (ch.equals("1"))
                System.out.println("WELCOME GUEST \n");
            else if (ch.equals("2"))
                System.out.println("WELCOME ADMIN \n");
            else if (ch.equals("3"))
                System.out.println("WELCOME LIBRARIAN \n");
            else if (ch.equals("4"))
                System.out.println("THANK YOU , SEE YA SOON");
            else
                System.out.println("\t\n WRONG CHOICE PLEASE ENTER A VALID NUMBAAA \n");



    }
```

I resolved using my last answer that you can see in here:

[Integer-restricted only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741365/integer-restricted-only/42741750#42741750)

Hope it helps you

Comment: Rather than just posting corrected code, I think it would be even more helpful if you would explain what was wrong with the asker’s code.

Comment: Ok let me see: ch = input.nextInt(); here there is a problem if user uses characaters and not numbers,  if (ch == 1) here theres another problem he thinks user used anumber, the do while is used in wonrg way do while is meant to used at least once, you know what i mean? at least run once my code if it is true run ti again etc... ITS NOT GOOD TO USE IT AS HE TRIED, explain all this will take me too long i don't see why i should do it when they didn't ask why