# Integer-restricted only?

Tags: java, integer

How can I limit the input to only integers (no doubles etc)? simple question for someone experienced to answer. if input is anything other than double then display error message, with ability to enter input again

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader =  new Scanner(System.in);
    int years;
    int minutes;

    System.out.println("Years to Minutes Converter");
    System.out.print("Insert number of years: ");
    years = reader.nextInt();

    minutes = years * 525600;


    System.out.print("That is ");
    System.out.print(minutes);
    System.out.print(" in minutes.");

    }
 }
```

Comment: You can't limit it. You can only check for invalid inputs after the fact.

Comment: Java commandline support is pretty limited, if you "really" need this kind of functionality,  you might consider having a look at the various bindings for the Curses API

Comment: The tags have already been edited, but for future reference: java and javascript are unrelated, so you shouldn't tag questions as javascript unless they actually involve that language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made this:

```
package reader;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );
        int years;
        int minutes;
        String data = null;

        System.out.println("Years to Minutes Converter");
        boolean test = false;

        while (test == false) {
            System.out.print("Insert number of years: ");
            String regex = "\\d+";
            data = reader.next();
            test = data.matches(regex);
            if (test == false) {
                System.out.println("There is a problem try again");
            }
        }
        years = Integer.valueOf(data);

        minutes = years * 525600;

        System.out.print("That is ");
        System.out.print(minutes);
        System.out.print(" in minutes.");

    }

}
```

It will say:

```
Years to Minutes Converter
```

Insert number of years: dsds
There is a problem try again
Insert number of years: ..
There is a problem try again
Insert number of years: 2
That is 1051200 in minutes.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain what you did with the "String data = null" and why a boolean was created?

Comment: Hi, the String data = null is used as a variable to get what user write, i use it because he can write anything, and if i used nextInt() i would have a Run time error as I just want numbers i used a regex comparing what he writes and if it is not number the boolean says false, then the while will go untill he writes numbers :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

Returns `true` if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an `int` value in the default radix using the `nextInt()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

Example code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");

while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
    sc.next();

int num1 = sc.nextInt();
int num2;

System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");

do {
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
        sc.next();
    num2 = sc.nextInt();
} while (num2 < num1);

System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2);
```

You don't have to `parseInt` or worry about `NumberFormatException`. Note that since `hasNextXXX` methods doesn't advance past any input, you may have to call `next()` if you want to skip past the "garbage", as shown above.